# query nested property of a list in MongoDB with C# Driver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongodb structured in this way :

```
  public class CarModel
{

    [BsonElement("Carname")]
    public string Carname { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("Color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }


    [BsonElement("Price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
                 

           
}

public class Producer
{

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Producer")]
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CarModel")]
    public List<CarModel> CarModel { get; set; }

}
```

I've made an asp.net core MVC application for make CRUD operation on this database.
now i want to insert a new list of CarModel inside a Producer, but before i want to check if one of the Carname present on this list is already present inside the DB :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateListino(Producer listino)
    {
        try
        {

            var document = _dbContext._database.GetCollection<Producer>("ListinoAuto");
            var builder = Builders<Producer>.Filter;
            long count = 0;

            foreach (var item in listino.CarModel)
            {
                var filter = builder.Eq(x => x.Producer, listino.Producer) & builder.Where(b => b.CarModel.Any(a => a.Carname == item.Carname));
                count += document.Find(filter).CountDocuments();
            }


            if (count == 0)
            {
               //Do Something
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Car model Already exist";
                return View("CreateListino", listino);
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

i really don't like to use the foreach statement for loop trough the CarModel received by the view, so I'm asking if there is a metod to compare the List and the database in one single query.
i want to look at only carname, not the other properies.

thank you